# ARIMA adjusted $R^2$

Tags: regression, arima, r-squared

I would like to know the variance explained by my ARIMA model. Is there something analogous to the adjusted $R^2$ in multiple regression that I can use to asses explained variance of my ARIMA model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use adjusted $R^2$ in ARIMA just as you would in a linear regression for cross-sectional data. The interpretation does not change. The same holds true for $R^2$.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to apply this and get exactly what I was looking for.